# Can't boot from SSD after it was moved into an external case

Tags: raspberry-pi, dd, ssd, external-hdd, clone

I used a SSD in an ASMT 2105 harddrive docking station connected to my Pi4 for installation (Raspbian Pi OS).

After moving the SSD into a smaller external SSD case, the Pi won't boot anymore (no ssh login).

I suspect it has something to do with the PARTUUIDs in my fstab but I don't know exactly what to change them to.

This is my fstab:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=11ac2c4c-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=11ac2c4c-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

This is the output of `ls /dev/disk/by-id -lah` after I connected the backup SSD in it's external case after I booted from the docking station.

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 160 Mar 13 10:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 140 Mar 13 07:32 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Mar 13 07:32 ata-ADATA_SX900_02628130500400001537 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar 13 07:32 ata-ADATA_SX900_02628130500400001537-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar 13 07:32 ata-ADATA_SX900_02628130500400001537-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Mar 13 10:17 usb-External_USB3.0_201703310007F-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar 13 10:18 usb-External_USB3.0_201703310007F-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar 13 10:18 usb-External_USB3.0_201703310007F-0:0-part2 -> ../../sdb2
```

And `ls /dev/disk/by-uuid/ -lah` shows:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  80 Mar 13 10:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 140 Mar 13 07:32 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar 13 10:21 37CA-39EC -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar 13 10:21 a4af13c6-d165-4cbd-a9f6-c961fef8255d -> ../../sda2
```

I tried changing `PARTUUID=11ac2c4c-01/02` to `/dev/sda1/2` but that didn't work.

Unfortunately I have no HDMI micro cable so I can't see what the Pi4 shows while booting.

Comment: May you can see the log, after change back to the internal. Can you share with us your grub settings?

Comment: As far as I understand the Pi4 uses an EEPROM boot loader and no grub.

Comment: No, the PARTUUID would not need to be changed, chances are, the USB enclosure is the issue - do you know the USB vendor/product id of the enclosure? (i.e. the output of `lsusb` with the enclosure connected and with a drive in it)

Comment: Try to change the PARTUUID to UUID `UUID=37CA-39EC /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2 

UUID=a4af13c6-d165-4cbd-a9f6-c961fef8255d  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1`

Comment: @k-att: I tried that but still no login.
I have ordered a micro HDMI cable which should arrive tomorrow, hopefully that gives me an idea what's going wrong.

@JaromandaX It's a: `152d:0578 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS578 SATA 6Gb/s`

Comment: The HDMI, good idea. Anyway... The smaller case working? Can you try it from another computer?

Comment: @JaromandaX After googling for that JMicron adapter, I suspect that it might have to do something with the corruption of my original installation (before this post).
I've ordered a different SATA/USB adapter and will try again.

Comment: `https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg180465.html` ?

Comment: @K-att Hmm strange, it seems to work without problems on my Ubuntu laptop but on the Pi4 (Raspbian 64bit, booted from the dock) it takes minutes to mount it and then it locks up when I try to access files on it.
That particular controller seems to be buggy for others too.
I will try with the replacement I've ordered.

Comment: @K-att The strange thing is that it worked on my 32bit installation for two years now without any problems.. then 3 days ago my filesystem got trashed.
Thanks for the help, hopefully this will be resolved by the new adapter.

Comment: @Vindolin - `JMicron` that explains it

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was the JMicron controller with the USB IDs 152d:0578  that caused the problem.

I installed the SSD into a similar case with an ASMT105x controller and everything worked right away.